# Sort a bar graph

Tags: sorting, powerbi

I have some simple data in a spreadsheet that I want to display in Power BI.  It is average volume per hour.  Hours are 0-23.

Requirements for the bar graph.

Use a bar graph.
Sort the bars from top to bottom by hour.
Color the bars in a diverging scheme based on the volume.
Show the hour and the data value for every bar.

I am also showing average volume by hour and day of week, average volume by month, etc. on the same report.  So I don't want to do anything when sorting the bar graph that will change the sort of the data in the other visualizations.

The bar graph as defined by the defaults has the hours in the reverse order (0 at the bottom and 23 at the top), only hours divisible by 5 are shown, and only a few data values are displayed.

Here is the screen capture of this bar graph next to a heat map (conditionally-formatted matrix).  As you can see the graph is upside down and some of the required features are missing.  Also, it would also be nice if I could control the amount of white space between the bars.

[image: Bar graph next to matrix]

I have scoured the configuration for the bar graph and have been unable to determine how to meet my requirements.  How can I make the bar graph behave as required?

Answer (score 0):

Having no other answers, I'll provide what I found.

I was able to correct the sorting:

1. Select the visual.
2. Expand the *Y axis* properties.
3. Change *Type* to Categorical.  This shows every category label and permits sorting.
4. Turn off *Y axis*.

I can now control sort order in the top right of the viz.

I also tried adjusting several other properties to try to improve the appearance.

- *Minimum category width* adjusts the height (thickness) of the bar.
  Unfortunately, the minimum is 20, so my result is way too tall.
- *Inner padding* controls the white space between the bars.

[image: Sorted bar chart]